# Fourier coefficients of a non-atomic measure on the unit cirle

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $0<\lambda<1$ and $\pi:\Pi_{\mathbb{N}} \{0,1\}\to S^1$ be the continuous map from the product space of $\{0,1\}$ over the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ onto the unit circle $S^1$. Let $\mu$ be the measure on $\{0,1\}$ with $\mu(0)=\lambda$ and $\mu(1)=1-\lambda$. Then the product measure $\mu^{\mathbb{N}}$ of $\mu$ gives a  probability measure on $\Pi_{\mathbb{N}}\{0,1\}$. Use $\mu_{\lambda}$ to denote the Borel probability measure on $S^1$ which is the push-forward of $\mu^{\mathbb{N}}$ by $\pi$.

Question: can we calculate the Fourier coefficients $\{\hat{\mu}_{\lambda}(n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ of  $\mu_{\lambda}$ (here $\hat{\mu}_{\lambda}(n):=\int_{S^1}\bar{z}^n\,d\mu_{\lambda}(z)$)?

Comment: What is THE continuous map from the product to $S^1$ ? There are many such maps.

Comment: Let $x=\{x_i\}_{i\geq 0}\in \Pi_{\mathbb{N}}\{0,1\}$. Identify $S^1$ with $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\pi(x)=\sum_{i\geq 0}\dfrac{x_i}{2^i}\mod 1$.